# $E\left[\prod_{i=1}^nX_i\right]=\prod_{i=1}^nE\left[X_i\right]$ for all independent and real-valued random variables

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory, expectation

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ be a measurable space and $X_1,\ldots,X_n:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ be independent random variables with $\color{red}{\prod_{i=1}^nX_i\in\mathcal{L}^1(P)}$ $\;\Rightarrow$
$$E\left[\prod_{i=1}^nX_i\right]=\prod_{i=1}^nE\left[X_i\right]$$
*Proof*:

- Let $$f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}\;,\;\;\;x\mapsto\prod_{i=1}^nx_i$$
- From basic facts, we know that $f$ is $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$-$\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable
- Let $X:=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ and $P_X:=P\circ X^{-1}$.
- Since $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are independent, we've got $$P_X=\bigotimes_{i=1}^nP_{X_i}\tag{1}$$
- Thus, \begin{equation}\begin{split}
  E\left[\prod_{i=1}^nX_i\right]&=&\int f(x)\;P_X(dx)\\
  &\stackrel{(2)}{=}&\int\cdots\int x_1\cdot\ldots\cdot x_n\;P_{X_1}(dx_1)\cdots P_{X_n}(dx_n)\\
  &\stackrel{(*)}{=}&\int x_1\;P_{X_1}(dx_1)\;\cdots\int x_n P_{X_n}(dx_n)
  \\&=&\prod_{i=1}^nE\left[X_i\right]
  \end{split}\end{equation}

**Question**: Does $(*)$ hold without further explanations (e.g. Fubini's theorem)? Moreover: How can we show that the $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ assumption holds iff $X_1,\ldots,X_n\in\mathcal{L}^1(P)$.

Comment: Though Fubini's theorem indeed kills the problem, one may use more pedestrian arguments (dominated convergence) to address integrability issues and also provide a solution. That is the beauty of probability that makes arguments nicer than in plain measure and integration theory.

Answer (score 0):

Once you write an integral over $\mathbb R^n$ as a product/iteration of integrals, we have to justify it. In this context, note that $|x_1\dots x_n|$ is integrable with respect to the measure $P_{X_1}(dx_1)\;\cdots\int x_n P_{X_n}(dx_n)$.

For the red part, we have to use the fact that if $U$ and $V$ are independent and bounded random variables, then $\mathbb E[UV]=\mathbb E[U]\mathbb E[V]$. To this this, start from the case where $U$ and $V$ are linear combination of $\sigma(U)$ (respectively $\sigma(V)$) measurable sets, then approximate. 
Finally, consider $U_n:=U\chi\{ |U|\leqslant n\}   $, $V_n:=V\chi\{ |V|\leqslant n\}$, use the previous case and conclude by dominated convergence.

Comment: I thought that $(1)$ would imply $(2)$. Then $(*)$ follows from basic facts about the integral (at least if we assume that each $X_i$ is non-negative or integrable).

Comment: Yes, (1) implies (2). And indeed, what you mention in the second sentence of your comment is the assumptions of Fubini's theorem.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with regards integrability that require some explanation.

1. By definition, independence of $\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$ means that for any Borel sets $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ if the real line, $\mathbb{P}[X_1\in A_1,\ldots,X_n\in X_n]=
   \mathbb{P}[X_1\in A_1]\cdot\ldots\cdot\mathbb{P}[A_n\in A_n]$.
   With a little more effort (starting with simple functions, induction and what not) we can see that independence of $\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$ is independent iff
   $$E[f_1(X_1)\cdot\ldots f_n(X_n)]=E[f(X_1)]\cdot\ldots\cdot E[f_n(X_n)]$$
   for all bounded measurable functions $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ on the real line.
2. We now show that $Y=X_1\cdot\ldots\cdot X_n$ is integrable:
   Consider the function $\phi_m(x)=\max(-m,\min(x,m))$. Each $\phi_m$ is a nice (Borel) measurable bounded function. Hence $f_m(Y_j)\in \mathcal{L}_1(P)$ and and $|\phi_m(X_j)|\leq |X_j|$ for all $j=1,\ldots,n$ and $m\in\mathbb{N}$.
   Then, by Fatou's lemma and dominated convergence
   \begin{align}
   E[|Y|]&=\liminf_m E[|\phi_m(X_1)|\cdot\ldots\cdot |\phi_m(Y_n)|]\\
   &=\liminf_mE[|\phi_m(X_1)|]\cdot\ldots\cdot E[|\phi_m(X_n)|]\\
   &=E[|X_1|]\cdot\ldots\cdot E[|X_n|]<\infty
   \end{align}
   3.Now that we have integration issues out of the way, the conclusion follows again by dominated convergence:
   \begin{align}
   E[Y]&=E[X_1\cdot\ldots\cdot X_n]=E[\lim_m\,\phi_m(X_1)\cdot\ldots\cdot\phi_m(X_n)]\\
   &=\lim_mE[\phi_m(X_1)\cdot\ldots\cdot\phi_m(X_n)]=\lim_mE[\phi_m(X_1)]\cdot\ldots\cdot E[\phi_m(X_n)]\\
   &=E[X_1]\cdot\ldots\cdot E[X_n]
   \end{align}