# Assume that $X,Y$ are independent random variables. Show that if $\mathbb{E}(X)=\mathbb{E}(Y)=0$, then $\mathbb{E}(XY)=0.$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, random-variables

I am currently attempting to understand the proof for this measure theory proposition:

> Assume that $X,Y$ are independent random variables. Show that if $\mathbb{E}(X)=\mathbb{E}(Y)=0$, then $\mathbb{E}(XY)=0.$

Using the following the following theorem, I found a proof that I have a few questions about:

> The random $X,Y$ are independent $\iff$ $\mathbb{E}(f(X)g(Y))=\mathbb{E}(f(X))\mathbb{E}(g(Y))$ holds for all Borel measurable bounded functions $f,g$.

*The Proof*

Let $f_{n}(x):= \max\{-n,\min\{x,n\}\}$. By the theorem, since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, we have that $\mathbb{E}(f_n(X)f_n(Y))=\mathbb{E}(f_n(X))\mathbb{E}(f_n(Y)).$ $\color{red}{\text{Therefore by the integrability of $X$ and $Y$ we can pass through the limit, giving us zero}}$ on the right hand side$._{\Box}$

**My question**

I do not understand the statement in $\color{red}{red}$, can someone make this more precise and write out formally what they mean by "*by the integrability of $X$ and $Y$ we can pass through the limit*" so I can understand it better?

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4077697/121671)  is a slightly generalization to the argument you described.

Comment: @OliverDiaz - Wow, thank you for all your help, Oliver! You really went above and beyond for the sake of my understanding. It’s helped a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are familiar with [dominated convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) notice that

1. $f_n(X)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty} X$ pointwise,
2. $|f_n(X)|\leq |X|$,
3. $X$ is assumed to be integrable ($E[|X|]=\int |X|\,dP<\infty$).

Then by dominated convergence
$$
\int f_n(X)\,dP\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\int X\,dP=E[X]$$
similarly for $Y$.

There is still the issue of the integrability of $XY$, This is a consequence of Fatou's lemma (another version of dominated convergence in a way)

$$\int|XY|\,dP=\int\lim_n |f_n(X)||f_n(Y)|\,dP\leq \liminf_n\int |f_n(X)||f_n(Y)|\,dP=\liminf_nE[|f_n(X)||f_n(Y)|]$$
By independence and by dominated convergence
$$\liminf_nE[|f_n(X)||f_n(Y)|]=\liminf_nE[|f_n(X)|]\,E[|f_n(Y)|]=E[|X|]\,E[|Y|]<\infty$$